# IntelliJ IDEA can't find remote deploy option

Tags: java, deployment, intellij-idea, raspberry-pi

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 13.02 and I like to deploy my Java application to my Raspberry Pi.

The manual says that I can configure remote server at (Choose Tools | Deployment | Configuration on the main menu), but there is no menu entry like this. Furthermore I should have installed the Remote Hosts Access plug-in but I can't find it. Can you tell me please how to deploy to a remote host the right way ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the plugin SourceSync: http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7374?pr=idea_ce.

You can find a howto guide at https://github.com/fioan89/sourcesync

Answer (score 2):

You can use Raspberry pi for Intellij http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7738 which allows you to run and debug your application directly on the pi through ease.